# In the Travelport Ticketing Issuance API scenario, a ticket API failed due to an "INVALID ND LINKAGE"

Tags: travelport-api

**Our queries to Travelport support team:**

> We are facing some issues with the ticket API. An error occurred four
> times, and the booking was not confirmed due to an "INVALID ND
> LINKAGE" issue. as well as one more issue that is "Host error during
> ticket issue-LINK UNAVBL/CALL VENDOR". In the auto ticketing scenario
> (AirTicketing Req API) scenario, we got a "Host error" during ticket
> issuance. We don't know the exact reason for this failure case
> ("INVALID ND LINKAGE"), so please guide us through what happened while
> booking OID (OfficeId-PCC) travelport GDS.

Answer (score 0):

**Travelport Response from [Travelport Support team Link](https://travelportprod.service-now.com/):**

> Host error during ticket issue  "INVALID ND LINKAGE" error implies
> printer connections is not done yet. In uapi, you need to add printer
> devices in uapi portal(aka admin portal) by yourself.  I have seen
> your printer device are not setup in prod admin portal.
>
> You should be having your admin portal credentials with you if not,
> please contact Travelport Account Manager to assist with the same,
> they can raise request to access admin portal. We API Support, do not
> have authorization to do this for you.
>
> Please find the step to step guide to do the printer connections
> https://support.travelport.com/webhelp/uapi/uAPI.htm#Getting_Started/AdminPortal/Printer_Connections.htm